# "adaptToUpdatedData: false" in highcharts don`t works if I put series in chart with "addSeries"

Tags: highcharts, navigator

I added 2 series in chart with "addSeries". Set property navigator.adaptToUpdatedData to false. Then I update data for series with "setData", if user zooms chart, but navigator is updated. If I update only 1 serie all works right. How fix it?

Example:

```
    <https://jsfiddle.net/zrxv30sh/1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Y̶o̶u̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶i̶n̶e̶ ̶b̶o̶t̶h̶ ̶s̶e̶r̶i̶e̶s̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶i̶t̶i̶a̶l̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶n̶a̶v̶i̶g̶a̶t̶o̶r̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶.̶

```
 n̶a̶v̶i̶g̶a̶t̶o̶r̶:̶ ̶{̶
     a̶d̶a̶p̶t̶T̶o̶U̶p̶d̶a̶t̶e̶d̶D̶a̶t̶a̶:̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶,̶
     s̶e̶r̶i̶e̶s̶:̶ ̶[̶{̶
        d̶a̶t̶a̶:̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶
     }̶,̶ ̶{̶ 
        d̶a̶t̶a̶:̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶2̶
     }̶]̶
}̶,̶
```

D̶e̶m̶o̶:̶ ̶h̶t̶t̶p̶s̶:̶/̶/̶j̶s̶f̶i̶d̶d̶l̶e̶.̶n̶e̶t̶/̶B̶l̶a̶c̶k̶L̶a̶b̶e̶l̶/̶n̶v̶m̶r̶y̶z̶L̶g̶/̶

After dig deeper into I found that the problem is with this part of the code:

```
   data.forEach(function(item){
      data2.push([item[0],item[1]+50,item[2]+50,item[3]+50,item[4]+50])
    })
    chart.series[0].setData(data);
    chart.series[1].setData(data2);
    chart.hideLoading();
```

Because `chart.series[1]` is defined as a navigator series which means that this setData config updates the navigator series.

Changing to `chart.series[2]` fix the issue.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w3cfLmqt/

Comment: When i create chart, i haven`t data for series. And in your demo only first zoom work right.

Comment: @КонстантинЗорин check my edit above

Comment: Thank you. But it works very strange.

Comment: @КонстантинЗорин `But it works very strange.` Could you explain?

Comment: Why chart.series[1] is defined as a navigator series only if I use "addSeries"?

Comment: In most cases, the navigator series is the last series in the `chart.series` array. So let's say that the initial config is two series object with the data, and the navigator will be a third one base on the first series. But in your case, there is no initial series and the order is: 1. Added first series, 2. Navigator series is created base on the added series, 3. Added second series